# Angular Hide side menu without javascript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I simply copy some code from google but the issue is for toggle they use javascript and I don't want to use javascript. I am using it by bootstrap 5.

My code

```
<div class="wrapper d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <nav id="sidebar">
        <div class="custom-menu">
            <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 pt-5">
            <h1><a href="index.html" class="logo">Splash</a></h1>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components mb-5">
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false"
                        class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>


        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content  -->
    <div id="content" class="p-4 p-md-5 pt-5">

        <h2 class="mb-4">Sidebar #02</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et
            dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
            ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
            nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
            anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

On `sidebarCollapse` they use this code in javascript

```
(function($) {

    "use strict";

    var fullHeight = function() {

        $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        $(window).resize(function(){
            $('.js-fullheight').css('height', $(window).height());
        });

    };
    fullHeight();

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
      $('#sidebar').toggleClass('active');
  });

})(jQuery);
```

I need to know how can I convert this code in typescript and use it without javascript? Front code is working fine but stuck on this toggle to hide and show sidemenu

Comment: You can't. JS is required for listening to clicks etc. What do you mean about typescript? There's no typescript here.

Comment: you don't want to use JS but Bootstrap is using JS... so contradicting.